# Classifier algorithms that can be trained with only "good" data

Tags: artificial-intelligence, classification

I'm trying to find a suitable classifier to work for my application. I really like Support Vector Machines for this, but I've come across a problem with my input data.

The user trains the classifier using real-world recorded audio. There are only two classes - 'Good' and 'Bad'.

My issue is that almost all of the training data will be 'good' - it's very unlikely to encounter 'bad' information during an on-site training run.

Is there an algorithm that works like an SVM, but returns a result of how well the new data fits to a 'good' line? Or within an upper and a lower 'good' hyperplane (that would be ideal, as I'd expect the tolerances to be different across several dimensions).

Alternatively, is there an algorithm I could use to automatically generate bad points for my training data?

An idea I had is that for each sample point, for each continuous axis, I...

- Get the value of the point on the chosen axis (v)
- Determine the maximum and minimum value for that axis on all points that share the same discrete values and have nearby continuous values ('min' and 'max')
- Add a 'bad' point at v + (max - min) and v - (max - min) to help guide the SVM.

This will probably force the SVM to work in a higher dimension, but it seems to me it should do the trick?

Comment: This sounds similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76420/classifier-for-only-one-class) over on Cross Validated (Stats SE). More generally, this is a type of one-class classification, so you might want to look look into that.

Comment: Had no such thing that such a thing existed - and it's in scikit-learn, the very framework I'm already using.

Thanks for your help! This is EXACTLY what I'm looking for.